# How to list the visited link on the same domain with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, history, browser-history

I want to do some script that see what the user visited links , as example:
user visited :

```
/profile
/profile/settings
/logout
```

A javascript code that can list all of these visited paths by the user ,
I tried the History Object but it didn't the way I want to do it ,

Is there any alternatives ?
And thanks for your time :)

Comment: How long do you want to "save" this data? - For example you could save every page entry in the localStorage.

Comment: Seems like your trying to round about get analytical data for the site.  There are any number of analytical things you could use, most notibaly google analytics, if you don't want to write your own solution.

Comment: I oftern use `window.onpopstate = history.onpushstate = () => { // send via socket.io, websocket or ajax }`, you also have `window.addEventListener('hashchange',` if you use hashes, or your router may have events.. doing in js you can obtain various bits from window.navigator and window.performance which is unobtainable doing serverside, plop them in db.. walla you have a list

Comment: @YannickEich , I want to save it from the current session ,
Yeah I found the LocalStorage solution but I need some other solution that had to be included in one page not on every page on the website
And thanks for your reply Yannick

Comment: @Taplar, Sure great idea but I need to add the JS code in only one page and it will pick the links from the history or something like that,
Thanks for the reply Taplar